# Français international

Tags: accents-régionaux

Y a-t-il un français qui est considéré comme étant **le** français international?

Précision: Sous plusieurs occasions, on doit utiliser un français qui doit être lu par le monde entier (aux jeux olympiques par exemple).

Quel **accent** du français est utilisé dans ces circonstances? Ou y a-t-il une version adaptée de cette langue pour ces occasions?

Comment: Du moment où vous vous exprimez clairement et correctement en respectant la grammaire, peu importe votre accent.

Comment: Mon pere a du traduire pour ses etudiants quebecois, a Paris, quand ils n'arrivaient pas a se faire comprendre (a l'oral) a cause de leurs accents.

Comment: Oui, peu importe l'accent, du moment qu'il s'agit de celui des classes moyennes/supérieures parisiennes imposé par les télévisions, radios, films et séries françaises...

Comment: @jlliagre: Y compris les séries tournées dans le sud de la France...

Comment: Le français des journaux télévisés peut être une bonne base non ?

Comment: @mouviciel "Plus belle, la vie ..."

Comment: @Random « Bonne » je ne sais pas mais conforme à la réalité, oui.

Comment: @jlliagre pourquoi ce ne serait pas une « bonne » base ? :)

Comment: @jlliagre Ce français standard qui a l'arrogance de se dire « sans accent » alors qu'il n'est après tout qu'un accent parmi d'autres est associé à une discrimination, d'où mon hésitation à qualifier la base de « bonne ». http://www.slate.fr/story/109511/discrimination-accent

Comment: @jlliagre, je comprend l'ironie dans ta phrase, mais souvent les films traduits par la France doivent être retraduits par le Québec tellement ils sont incompréhensibles pour nous (loin d'être internationnal alors)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipédia a une réponse: le [français standard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_standard):

> Le français standard ou français normé désigne le français dénué de
>   tout accent ou régionalisme et dont la syntaxe, la morphologie et
>   l’orthographe sont décrits dans les dictionnaires, les ouvrages de
>   grammaire et manuels de rédaction tels que le Bescherelle ou Le Bon
>   Usage.
>
> On considère parfois que le français parlé dans la région de Tours
>   constitue le français de référence mais, le français est pluricentré,
>   il n'existe pas de définition généralement admise du français
>   standard.

Comment: En effet, un français parlé avec un accent régional, sans inférence du patois sous-jacent, sans référence au vocabulaire spécifique à cette région est parfaitement audible si le locuteur articule correctement. L'accent n'est pas un problème au contraire des régionalismes.

Comment: @cl-r "Mon père a du traduire pour ses étudiants québecois" = "Mon païr o du trodhuïr pr saïze aïtidiain kaybecwai"

Comment: @ChrisW Quelle horreur! Le français international tel que compris ou pratiqué au Québec ne sonne pas du tout comme ça. En fait, cette prononciation est tellement outrée qu'elle ne correspond plus qu'à une tentative alchimique d'obtenir la quintessence de toutes les différences à la norme que l'on peut observer au Québec. Quelqu'un qui parlerait ainsi, au Québec, aurait droit au même regard interrogatif qu'il aurait en France ou au Congo.